# best practice, for sql "select" queries that return more than 30k rows - Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance, select

I have some queries, currently I have a table where we use it to download reports, the query of that table is only a "select" that is searched by date range, it happens that the amount of record that it returns is quite a lot, it is say more than 30k, and I wanted to know if there is a good practice for downloading results that are very heavy in Postgres? For example, concept of data compression or something similar, the idea is that the download of my reports is extremely fast

Note that I have a B-tree index, for searching by date range.

I know that indexes are very good for specific queries, but for queries that return many rows, is there any technique to improve performance?

Comment: Is your problem related to inherent query performance, or to a network banwidth? 30k rows is no big deal nowadays. Does the query run fast when the result is saved locally?

Comment: The best practice is not to try to solve imaginary problems.  If you really want to be proactive, you can easily generate a query over any amount of fabricated (but real) data you want and measure what is actually happening.

Comment: You need some metrics because "fast", "slow", "heavy" are just opinions and can't be measured. 30k records is imho not a lot, but 100 bytes per record or 1GB per record, that does make a difference when traveling over the network. What are the metrics, what are your goals and where do you spend most of the time?